# Django 1.10 Apache2 mod_wsgi IOError: failed to write data

Tags: python, django, apache2, wget, mod-wsgi

I have a django site with

- django version 1.10.5
- djangorestframework==3.5.3

This website hosts files segregated by components for the users to be able to download them.

Since yesterday, I am seeing the following issue. For a couple of components, lets say 'a' and 'b', I am not able to download the files onto a Linux box. For the rest of the components, I am able to download the files.

The reason I say linux is because.. I downloaded the same files to my macbook and I am able to download without any issues.

On the Linux boxes, I see the following error:

`2017-01-05 15:06:18 (5.50 MB/s) - Read error at byte 10357143/35563520 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.`

And on the server side(**Initially was running django development server, now replaced with mod_wsgi and apache2**):

`[Thu Jan 05 15:21:18.588286 2017] [:error] [pid 24756] [remote 10.11.30.20:52525] mod_wsgi (pid=24756): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 05 15:21:18.588407 2017] [:error] [pid 24756] [remote 10.11.30.20:52525] IOError: failed to write data`

I thought it was an issue with the client. But I see the same issue with `wget`, `curl`, `httpie`

I already scanned all the relevant content that google returns for such errors with python/Django/wsgi/apache2 but couldn't find anything useful.

Also, here is the django generated wsgi.py I'm using for this site.

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DevServe.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update:

Python, apache and mod_wsgi versions:

```
AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured
```

Curl verbose output for working file download and failed file download. The first one is the failed download and the second one is the successful download.

```
root@xyz:/tmp/test# curl -vv -O http://x.x.x.x:8000/releases/media/releases/2017_01_05/xyz
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /releases/media/releases/2017_01_05/xyz HTTP/1.1
> Host: x.x.x.x:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 22:32:01 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 00:38:02 GMT
< Content-Length: 15430268
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< 
{ [1166 bytes data]
 46 14.7M   46 6983k    0     0  5624k      0  0:00:02  0:00:01  0:00:01 5622k* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
 79 14.7M   79 11.7M    0     0  5587k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 5590k
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

root@xyz:/tmp/test# curl -vv -O http://x.x.x.x:8000/releases/media/releases/2016_10_31/abc
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /releases/media/releases/2016_10_31/abc HTTP/1.1
> Host: x.x.x.x:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 22:32:31 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Last-Modified: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 23:17:24 GMT
< Content-Length: 108747612
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< 
{ [1165 bytes data]
100  103M  100  103M    0     0  4158k      0  0:00:25  0:00:25 --:--:-- 4275k
* Connection #0 to host x.x.x.x left intact
```

**mod_wsgi version and installation**
I have the latest version I could get by pip

```
pip freeze | grep wsgi
mod-wsgi==4.5.13
```

After updating the latest mod_wsgi version, I still see the same issue

```
[Mon Jan 09 12:05:54.582945 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29510] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 mod_wsgi/4.5.13 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 09 12:05:54.583000 2017] [core:notice] [pid 29510] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 09 12:06:51.974442 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29514] [remote 10.11.50.97:41884] mod_wsgi (pid=29514): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jan 09 12:06:51.974633 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29514] [remote 10.11.50.97:41884] IOError: Apache/mod_wsgi failed to write response data: Broken pipe.
[Mon Jan 09 12:06:54.086790 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29514] [remote 10.11.50.97:41886] mod_wsgi (pid=29514): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jan 09 12:06:54.086944 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29514] [remote 10.11.50.97:41886] IOError: Apache/mod_wsgi failed to write response data: Broken pipe.
```

Comment: What mod_wsgi version are you using? Are you using embedded mode or daemon mode of mod_wsgi? Generally it means that the HTTP client has closed the connection before reading the complete response. Are you sure the response content length is being set correctly?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am using mod_wsgi 3.4

This is the first time I am serving django site with apache and mod_wsgi. So I am not sure what embedded/daemon mode is. Also not sure about the response content length. I'll try to find whatever I can and will post an update.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I added curl verbose output for the successful and failed downloads which has the content length. That might be of any help with identifying the problem?

Comment: Your mod_wsgi version is over 50 releases behind and effectively over 5 years old. It is no longer supported.I would suggest upgrading it to latest if you can.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I updated mod_wsgi to v4.5.13 and restarted apache2 and still see the same errors. Added an update in the question with the same apache2 error.log

Comment: Have you worked out if you are using daemon mode? See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html Also, what do you have ``Timeout`` directive set to in Apache configuration?

Comment: I have `Timeout 300`
I will go through the blog post you shared and respond about daemon mode

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Added a comment on your blog. I modified apache2.conf and set the loglevel to info and I don't see this output in apache2/error.log or apache2/access.log. Is there any other file I should be looking into for this output?

"If the configuration is such that the WSGI application is running in embedded mode, then you will see:

mod_wsgi.process_group = ' ' "

Comment: Already answered. You can see from the test program that it sends the information as a response, so in your browser when you make a request.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I see the following string on the browser mod_wsgi.process_group = 'DevServe' | So I am assuming that I am already running in daemon mode.

Comment: Do you have system task which is periodically triggering an Apache restart/reload. Eg. log rotation.

Comment: @Graham: No I don't have anything like that. I believe apache itself performs log rotation once everyday but other than that, I don't have anything else that does restart/reload

Comment: You have PHP loaded into Apache, do you actually use it?

Comment: Yes I do. I have another php website running on the same machine.

Comment: Have you set ``MaxConnectionsPerChild`` directive?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton No and here are the contents of my apache2.conf config file http://pastebin.com/BYa4rFjR